# HTML pattern attribute for email validation

Tags: html

I need the email address of the user to match this format while registering.

```
name.name@gmail.com
```

He should not be able to enter @yahoo.com or @hotmail.com or anything else other than @gmail.com. Also, he is only allowed to enter lower case letters and a period [.] if he wants. May I please know how to achieve this? This is what I have got so far.

```
pattern ="[a-z.]+@gmail.com"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
/^([a-z0-9.])+\@gmail.com+$/
```

Comment: Should the semicolon be there as well?

Comment: No semicolon will not be there